# How can I filter columns that contains one name or another?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a Dataframe containing some columns with the brand of the product, a few questions from a questionnaire and a few answers. I want to filter only the columns containing the questions and the brand. This is what I've tried:

```
df.filter(regex=('brand','question'))
```

I tried to change a few things after *regex* but nothing worked. Is there anything I can do? I was hoping to use this sort of code, because what I am actually doing is filtering the columns after filtering the ids. So this is what my code looks like:

```
df[df['id'].isin(id_sample)].filter(regex=('brand','question'))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _This is what I've tried:_ What does that produce? Please provide a [mcve], including the current and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
df.filter(regex='brand|question')
```

**OR**

you can use a `list comprehension` as well:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'brand' in col or 'question' in col]
df = df[cols]
```